# Converting Pytorch model to Keras model with MMdnn IR interface Model

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

I have downloaded a pretrained Pytorch cifar model from this [link](http://ml.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/~chenxi/pytorch-models/cifar10-d875770b.pth) that it has a custom architecture. I want to convert this model to a Keras model. I know that there are some tools to do that. For example I can convert the Pytorch model to a standard model like onnx or [IR](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn).

Now I have used the [IR](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn) interface model and the following code to load and save the entire model:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
from  torch.autograd import Variable
import torch as th
from collections import OrderedDict

class CIFAR(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features, n_channel, num_classes):
        super(CIFAR, self).__init__()
        assert isinstance(features, nn.Sequential), type(features)
        self.features = features
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(n_channel, num_classes)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x

def make_layers(cfg, batch_norm=False):
    layers = []
    in_channels = 3
    for i, v in enumerate(cfg):
        if v == 'M':
            layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)]
        else:
            padding = v[1] if isinstance(v, tuple) else 1
            out_channels = v[0] if isinstance(v, tuple) else v
            conv2d = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=padding)
            if batch_norm:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels, affine=False), nn.ReLU()]
            else:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.ReLU()]
            in_channels = out_channels
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)

n_channel=128
cfg = [n_channel, n_channel, 'M', 2*n_channel, 2*n_channel, 'M', 4*n_channel, 4*n_channel, 'M', (8*n_channel, 0), 'M']
layers = make_layers(cfg, batch_norm=True)
model = CIFAR(layers, n_channel=8*n_channel, num_classes=10)
pretrained=True

if pretrained:
    m = th.load('MY_PATH/cifar10-d875770b.pth')
    state_dict = m.state_dict() if isinstance(m, nn.Module) else m
    assert isinstance(state_dict, (dict, OrderedDict)), type(state_dict)
    model.load_state_dict(state_dict)

torch.save(model, 'MY_PATH/pytorch.pth')
```

Now it's time to convert the above Pytorch model *pytorch.pth* to IR model.

In the cmd I enter this command from the example of [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn/blob/master/mmdnn/conversion/pytorch/README.md):

```
mmtoir -f pytorch -d IRModel --inputShape 3,32,32 -n pytorch.pth
```

But this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mmdnn\conversion\pytorch\pytorch_parser.py", line 76, in __init__
    model = torch.load(model_file_name)
  File "c:\users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 387, in load
    return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "c:\users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 574, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'CIFAR' on <module '__main__' from 'C:\\Users\\***\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\mmtoir.exe\\__main__.py'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\***\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\***\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\Scripts\mmtoir.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mmdnn\conversion\_script\convertToIR.py", line 192, in _main
    ret = _convert(args)
  File "c:\users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mmdnn\conversion\_script\convertToIR.py", line 92, in _convert
    parser = PytorchParser(model, inputshape[0])
  File "c:\users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mmdnn\conversion\pytorch\pytorch_parser.py", line 78, in __init__
    model = torch.load(model_file_name, map_location='cpu')
  File "c:\users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 387, in load
    return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "c:\users\***\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 574, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'CIFAR' on <module '__main__' from 'C:\\Users\\***\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\mmtoir.exe\\__main__.py'>
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's been long since this question was asked, I'll share the answer.

The solution in my case was fairly simple, I had installed mmdnn in an anaconda env. And the file `mmtoir` was stored in the following location:

> 'user_name/anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin/mmtoir'

And there needed to be an explicit reference of my Neural Network class in this file. Meaning in your case, you need to:

1) Locate this file

2) Copy the definition of CIFAR class

```
class CIFAR(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, features, n_channel, num_classes):
    super(CIFAR, self).__init__()
    assert isinstance(features, nn.Sequential), type(features)
    self.features = features
    self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(n_channel, num_classes)
    )

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.features(x)
    x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
    x = self.classifier(x)
    return x
```

into `mmtoir` file. Save it and run the command again.

And above is one of the two methods to solve this issue and is relatively simple. You can read this [discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/error-loading-saved-model/) for further details.

**Note:** MMdnn currently supports `PyTorch=0.4.0` only. So make sure your model was trained on the same version as well. With `PyTorch>0.4.0` all steps will run fine but will throw an error at the end.